# Notice: Undefined index: node-readmore in theme_preprocess_node()

Tags: theming

I am using this code on D7 for my themes template.php to replace default 'Read More' title with 'Read More →' (it just adds arrow):

```
function theme_preprocess_node(&$vars){
  $vars['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['title'] = str_replace("Read more","Read more →",$vars['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['title']);
}
```

It all works, but when clearing cache I get this error message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: node-readmore in theme_preprocess_node()
```

Comment: wrap the whole thing in an `if(!empty($vars['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore'])) {...}` and it will get rid of the notice. But you should be using [`theme_more_link()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_more_link/7).

Comment: You can always dpm($vars) to see what is being available on the page and then adjust your code from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the page view of the node not including the read more link.

e.g

```
function theme_preprocess_node(&$vars){
  if(!$vars['page']){
    $vars['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['title'] = t('Read more →'); 
  }
}
```

or perhaps

```
function theme_preprocess_node(&$vars){
  if(isset($vars['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore'])){
    $vars['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['title'] = t('Read more →'); 
  }
}
```

No need for the str_replace either if just setting the full text string.

Note, an alternative is to translate that text,

e.g with [stringoverrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) or in settings.php

```
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
  'Read more'      => 'Read more  →',
  'Old text 2'      => 'New text 2',
);
```